# update foreign keys when inserting to different table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables created

users
{
user_id --pk
username
}

```
topics
{
topic_id-- pk
content
}

created_topics
{
created_id--pk
user_id
topic_id
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) REFERENCES topics(topic_id)
}
```

When i run this query,

```
 insert into created_topics (user_id,topic_id) values (1,1);
```

i get this error...

> ```
> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxxxxxxxxxx`.`created_topics`, CONSTRAINT `created_topics_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))
> ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of any foreign key must be one of the values from the primary key. You can't insert values into the fields with foreign key constraint as you did above. First of all insert values into your users and topics tables. Then you can use(reference) only the values you have inserted into the primary keys in their respective foreign keys.